# Problems with int/String linked lists and variables

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-reference

I am having some trouble creating a linked list in Java. All of the guides I am following give examples using some kind of variable of type String, but the list I must create needs a type int. Using the type int will produce an error message when I try to call something like position.link because it says it cannot convert an int to a string.

For clarity, the main program should have Scanner ask for the int, and use that int to create a loop that creates each node. I have messed around with iterators and with just simple singular linked lists but I am not getting anywhere.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class SuitorLinkedList<Integer>
{
   private class SuitorListNode
   {
      private int suitor;
      private SuitorListNode link;

      public SuitorListNode()
      {
         suitor = 0;
         link = null;
      }

      public SuitorListNode(int newSuitor, SuitorListNode linkValue)
      {
         suitor = newSuitor;
         link = linkValue;
      }
   } // End of SuitorListNode inner class

   public class SuitorListIterator
   {
      public SuitorListNode position;
      private SuitorListNode previous; // previous value of position

      public SuitorListIterator()
      {
         position = head; // variable head of outer class
         previous = null;
      }

      public void restart()
      {
         position = head;
         previous = null;
      }

      public String next()
      {
         if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

         String toReturn = position.suitor;
         previous = position;
         position = position.link;
         return toReturn;
      }

      public boolean hasNext()
      {
         return (position != null); // Throws IllegalStateExpression if false
      } // Returns next value to be returned by next()

      public String peak()
      {
         if(!hasNext())
            throw new IllegalStateException();
         return position.suitor;
      }

      public void addHere(int newData)
      {
         if(position == null && previous != null) // At end of list, add to end
            previous.link = new SuitorListNode(newData, null);
         else if(position == null || previous == null) // List empty or position is head node
            head = new SuitorListNode(newData, head);
         else // previous and position are consecutive nodes
         {
            SuitorListNode temp = new SuitorListNode(newData, position);
            previous.link = temp;
            previous = temp;
         }
      }

      public void delete()
      {
         if(position == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
         else if (previous == null) // remove node at head
         {
            head = head.link;
            position = head;
         }
         else // previous and position are consecutive nodes
         {
            previous.link = position.link;
            position = position.link;
         }
      }

      private SuitorListNode head;
   }
   public SuitorListIterator iterator()
   {
      return new SuitorListIterator();
   }
}
```

I get this error every time I try, I've tried searching it up and using the toString() to help but it won't work:

```
SuitorLinkedList.java:60: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
         return position.suitor;
                        ^
```

I have tried creating the regular linked list and got this far:

```
public class SuitorList
{
   public class SuitorNode
   {
      public int suitor;
      public SuitorNode link;

      public SuitorNode()
      {
         suitor = 0;
         link = null;
      } // Initialize veriables

      public SuitorNode(int newSuitor, SuitorNode linkValue)
      {
         suitor = newSuitor;
         link = linkValue;
      } // Assigns values sent in from main
   } // End inner class

   private SuitorNode head; // Variable head of type SuitorNode (callback to Node program)
   // Allows head to point to a node

   public SuitorList()
   {
      head = null;
   } // Initialize variables
   // Memory space called head filled with null

   public void addToStart(int suitorNum)
   {
      head = new SuitorNode(suitorNum, head);
   } 

   // Creates node with head pointing to it at start of list
   // head will have a definition as an object with a suitor and link = head
   // If head = null, then link = null
   // head is repositioned to point to node

   public int size() // Reads size of list
   {
      int count = 0;
      SuitorNode position = head; // Variable position of type SuitorNode will equal value at head; position points where head is pointing
      while(position != null) // While list is not empty/ended
      {
         count++; // increase number of entries detected
         position = position.link; // getLink will make position = link, leading to next entry in list
      }
      return count; // Display size.
   }

   public void outputList()
   {
      SuitorNode position = head; // Position points to same thing head points to

      while(position != null) // While list is not empty/ended
      {
         System.out.println(position.suitor); // Print suitor
         position = position.link; // Go to next entry
      }
   }

   public void deleteNode(int count)
   {
      int moveCount = count - 1;
      SuitorNode position = head;

      while(head != link) // not winning
      {
         moveCount = count;
         checkEnd(); // Checks for win before causing potential problem with 1 suitor left
         checkTwoNumbersLeft(moveCount); // Takes care of movement when two nodes are left
         checkEndNode(moveCount); // Checks when, for example, 2 nodes away

         if(moveCount == count) // If checkEndNode and checkTwoNumbersLeft fail
         {
            position = position.link; // Move for first time
            moveCount = moveCount - 1;
         }

         checkEnd();
         checkEndNode2(moveCount); // When one movement is made already, deletes end node after

         if(moveCount == moveCount - 1) // if checkEndNode2 fails
            position = position.link.link; // 2nd deletion
         count = moveCount;
      }

      isWinner();
   } // End method deleteNode()

   public void checkTwoNumbersLeft(int moveCount)
   {
      SuitorNode position;
      if(position.link.link == null) // example: 1 5
      {
         createLoop();
         position = position.link.link; // Deletes the 5
         moveCount = moveCount - 2;
      } // Used just in case only two numbers are present
   } // End method checkTwoNumbersLeft()

   public void checkEnd()
   {
      SuitorNode position;
      if(position.link == null) // If at end of list
      {
         createLoop(); // creates a loop if the initial number has no next value
         isWinner(); // If a 1 is used, the entire if statement will trigger
      } // if true, head == link which will fall out of while in deleteNode()
   } // End method checkEnd()

   public void isWinner()
   {
      SuitorNode link;
      SuitorNode position;
      if(position == position.link)
      {
         head = link;
         System.out.println("The winner is Suitor " + position + "!");
      } 
   } // End method isWinner()

   public void checkEndNode2(int moveCount)
   {
      SuitorNode position;
      SuitorNode link;

      if(position.link.link == null) // 1 movement
      {
         position.link = null;
         createLoop();
         isWinner();
         moveCount = moveCount - 1;
      }
   } // End checkEndNode2()

   public void checkEndNode(int moveCount)
   {
      SuitorNode position;
      SuitorNode link;

      if(position.link.link.link == null) // no movements
      {
         position = position.link;
         position.link = null;
         createLoop();
         isWinner();
         moveCount = moveCount - 2;
      }
   } // End checkEndNode()

   public void createLoop()
   {
      SuitorNode position;
      SuitorNode link;

      if(link == null) // if at the end of the list
         link = head; // Sets link to point to where head points, AKA beginning of list
   } // End createLoop()
}
```

But when I do this, the variables *link*, *position*, and *head* always say they are not initialized unless I place them inside the method (which can mess up my code if I call the method while in the middle of the list).

My questions boil down to 1) How would I be able to convert the ints to strings in order to work with a linked list? and 2) Why are the variables in the program **SuitorList** requiring me to reinitialize them in every instance when I've tried placing them everywhere I could?

Comment: I have a very loose understanding of linked lists, and I haven't been able to wrap my head around most examples I come across.

Comment: What happens if you change the signature of the method with the error, from `public String peak()` to `public int peak()`, since you want it to return an `int`?  You probably want to do the same with the signature of `next()`, and the declaration of the `toReturn` variable inside `next()`.

Comment: I believe that was my issue, I'll just have to make sure that was the only one when I finish my main program.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your peek function is defined as the wrong type

```
public String peak()
{
    if(!hasNext())
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    return position.suitor;
}
```

It's defined as returning a `String`

Instead it should be defined as `suitor`'s type, an `int`

```
public int peak()
{
    if(!hasNext())
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    return position.suitor;
}
```

Same issue with `public String next()`, should instead be `public int next()`

Comment: Thank you, I knew reading from guides that were only using Strings were going to mess me up eventually. I will give any update if my main method shows any problems with anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

The variable **suitor** is given the variable type of *int*. It is possible to *turn* it into a string. By converting it;

```
public String peak() { if(!hasNext()) throw new IllegalStateException(); return Integer.toString(position.suitor); }
```

This method should get rid of that error. Or using `String.valueOf(position.suitor);`.